# Loop through array and MySQL query for each element - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-4

I have a table with a list of websites. Also I have a table with information about visits and conversions. In this table I have one row per website per day with columns visits and conversions. So I know which website had how many visits and conversions every day.

Now, I want to list all websites in a table with the sum of visits and conversions on this website over the last 30 days.

So what I do is I load all websites into an array with:

```
$websites = Website::all();
```

And then I loop through this array to get the additional data:

$complete_list = array();

```
foreach ($websites as $website) {

    $clicks = Stats::where(DATE INSIDE DATE RANGE)->where('website_id', '=', $website->id)->sum('visits');
    $complete_list[] = array(
       'website' => $website->id,
       'click'=> $clicks
    }; 
}
```

Same thing for conversions.

This works but does not seem the best way to do this...

Does anyone have an idea on how to simplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using Eager Loading? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Not until now ;) Worked perfectly!